# refcursor returning an object that contain list of all data

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, java, cursors

I am new to pl/SQL, please help me to create a procedure!

The scenario:
I have categories and subcategories and each category and subcategory has a description.  I  want the procedure to return a `refcursor` with a list of objects that contain `level1 menu'`s list, then all submenu lists based on the parent menu with description.

Example:

```
Mainmenu
|
|- menu1
       |--submenu1
       |--submenu2
|
|-menu2
       |--submenu1
       |--submenu2
```

Java class definition:

```
class Menu{
    String desc;
    list<Menu> menu;
}
```

I would like to have a stored procedure in Oracle pl/SQL to populate the object in Java.

Please guide me with `refcursor` returning an object that contains all needed data!

Comment: What code do you have so far? It's all well and good being new to PL/SQL, but you won't learn anything if we write the code for you...

Comment: Hi Phir, you are absolutely right, I have wriiten the code also for the same, but i was not able to think about how i need to put the data in one refsursor as one menu can have multiple submenu

Comment: do i need to create object as  menu_object(string,menu_object) till level 1 menu gets populated  and then insert it to one temporary table , and then do the same for other level 1 menu, because at last i want to list of all menus, Please corrent me if i am wrong

Comment: SQL is a set-based language.  I'm not sure that I understand what you want to be returned?  Do you want a result set with 1 column and 6 rows?  Do you want 2 columns with 6 rows with 1 column telling you what "level" the menu item is?  Something else?

Comment: {
  "main_menu": [
    {
      "menu1": {
        "DESC": "menu1 Description",
        "menu1submenu1": [{
          
          
          "DESC": "menu1submenu1 Description",
           "menu1submenu1submenu1": [
            
             
             
             ]
          
          
        }]
      }
    },
    {
      "menu2": {
      
      /*same as menu 1*/
      }
    }
  ]
}

Comment: You've posted an answer that appears to be something that should be edited into your question.  So you want to return a single JSON string?  If so, you don't want a cursor, just return a `CLOB` or a `VARCHAR2` depending on the size of the JSON string you need to support.  If you are using SQL, I assume that you have tables with data in them that have the data you want to convert into a JSON string.  You'll need to tell us what those tables and that data looks like.  What version of Oracle are you using?  12.1 adds additional support for JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic example, but hope it helps.  Recommend you use this template and fill in more information since part of the benefit of writing code is learning.  You'll have to figure out how to pass your JSON data to a database or schema. This is relevant to PL/SQL only.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE <procedure_name> (
    x1   IN VARCHAR2(10),
    x2   IN VARCHAR2(10),
    ...
    RECORDS OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
    )
AS 
   v_sql  CLOB /* or use VARCHAR2(32767) */
BEGIN
<your logic>
v_sql := v_sql || '<your query statement to return values'>

OPEN RECORDS FOR v_sql;

END <procedure_name>
;
```

/* to text do this, define a variable and pass output to it in SQL-Plus */

```
var v_test REFCURSOR
begin
 <procedure_name>(x1 => value1, x2 => value2, :v_test);
end;

SELECT :v_text from dual;
```